# Firefox is already running, but is not responding error when running owasp-mantra-ff in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, virtualbox, kali-linux

I have setup a Kali Linux VM inside VirtualBox and I updated it using the following command.

`sudo apt-get update`

Afterwards, I ran the following command to install owasp-mantra-ff and its dependencies.

`sudo apt-get install owasp-mantra-ff`

`sudo apt-get install xterm`

After successful completion, once I run the owasp-mantra-ff, an error window pops up which is saying the following.

***Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.***

In the terminal, the following could be seen.

```
owasp-mantra-ff
firefoxportable:Debug/Info: 0=./OWASP Mantra
firefoxportable:Debug/Info: dir=/usr/share/owasp-mantra-ff
firefoxportable:Debug/Info: Current Dir=/usr/share/owasp-mantra-ff/Mantra

(process:5813): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:00:11.464: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Welcome to the Linux version of firefox 18.0 in portable mode. Feedback is NOT disabled.
firefoxportable:Debug/Info: Profile Directory already exists!
firefoxportable:Debug/Info: firefox is now closed.
./OWASP Mantra: 51: yaf-splash: not found
firefoxportable:Debug/Info: firefoxportable is now closed.
```

**Additional Information:**

```
cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2022.1"
VERSION_ID="2022.1"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
```

Any valuable suggestion/ solution to troubleshoot this issue is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do all the dependencies?   https://www.kali.org/tools/owasp-mantra-ff/#:~:text=Mantra%20is%20a%20browser%20especially,testing%20procedures%20within%20the%20browser.

Comment: @John Thanks. Yes, I installed the only dependency required, xterm. Is there any other dependency which is required?

Comment: There was a list of dependencies in the article.  I have not installed owasp myself so I am not sure what in particular.

Comment: @John The article that you are referring to, states only one dependency which is xterm.

Comment: `$ firefox -V` -> `Mozilla Firefox 99.0` - so? Really "18.0"?

Comment: @Hannu firefox -V -> Mozilla Firefox 91.5.0esr

Comment: Copied from above: `Welcome to the Linux version of firefox 18.0 in portable mode`

Comment: @Hannu Yes it is trying to open up in firefox 18.0 in portable mode. Any suggestions? I am a beginner when it comes to working with Kali Linux.

Comment: Well, "18.0" indicates a REALLY old FF; "XP SP2" stated as requirement here -> https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/18.0/system-requirements/ - if you REALLY have an that old FF, anything could be caused by that simple fact as you try to start it.

Comment: @Hannu Yes, it is trying to open up in this old portable version instead of the existing latest version (91.5.0esr).

Comment: https://www.kali.org/tools/owasp-mantra-ff/ - I assume you did you get it from there and nowhere else. Sorry can't help more,

Comment: @Hannu Yes. I installed it using the sudo apt-get install owasp-mantra-ff command.

Comment: Looks like a version number mismatch all over the place; inconsistencies similar to this indicates that there might be other types of more serious trouble. NOW: `firefoxportable:Debug/Info: Profile Directory already exists!` -> rename that dir and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the owasp-mantra-ff command in the root terminal solved the issue for me.